# How can I pass an accepted socket from a parent process to its child process?

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

**Note:**  Based on the answer below, I think that I have not properly communicated this question.  I am currently re-writing it with code to be more clear.

---

I'm writing a python server which accepts connections multiple clients and stores them.

If I print the properly connected socket which is used to speak with one of the connected clients, I'd get something like the following as output:

```
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('3.3.3.3', 1234), raddr=('4.4.4.4', 63402)>
```

where for the purposes of privacy I've replaced my server's IP with 3.3.3.3 and the client's IP with 4.4.4.4.  What I was really *hoping* would work, would be to save the information to a file in the format:

```
4 2049
```

and then when the child process boots, it would pass this information to a socket constructor using:

```
recovered_client = socket(AF_INET, 2049, 0, 4)
```

But this does not work.  When I apply this process and print the recovered client, I see the following:

```
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0>
```

It seems that the fields *laddr* and *raddr* from the original connection are not recovered by passing the file descriptor to the constructor.

I tried manually repairing this by adding the host and port from laddr and raddr to the file also, and then connecting with the command:

```
recovered_client.connect(('4.4.4.4', 63402))
```

But this yields the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
```

---

As an experiment, I left the connection open in the parent process, then had the child process accept a new fresh connection and print it, and what I got was:

```
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('3.3.3.3', 1234), raddr=('75.159.78.189', 49709)>
```

In other words, a new connection has been made, with the same value for *fd*, with a different client port.  The original connection was never closed, but rather it hung indefinitely because, as intended, the parent process froze when it called the child process.

So this means I have two different active connections (although one was frozen), whose sockets have the same file descriptors.  Does this mean that the value assigned to the field *fd* for a socket is relative to the process that created it?

If so, my approach is clearly hopeless.  How can I pass my client's connection created in my parent process to its child process?

Comment: Define 'connected client'. Do you mean 'accepted socket'? If so, what makes you think you can reconstitute a connected socket from text? You can't.

Comment: Yes I meant an accepted socket.  I'll edit my question to reflect that.  As for your second question, I thought that the *fd* field was a unique number assigned by the operating system to the connection, similar to how sockets are mapped to integers in C.  So if I can't do it by text, how can I do this?  I tried pickling the accepted socket but sockets cannot be pickled.

Comment: @user207421 based on your comment, you mind find the accepted answer interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If so, my approach is clearly hopeless. How can I pass my client's connection created in my parent process to its child process?

A child inherits all open file descriptors from its parent. There's no need to "pass" anything.  Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import socket


s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('localhost', 2049))
s.listen(5)


def child_process(fd, addr):
    while True:
        data = fd.recv(10)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        print('read:', data)

    print('client {} has disconnected'.format(addr))


def main():
    while True:
        c_fd, c_addr = s.accept()
        print('new connection from', c_addr)

        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            # This is the parent process
            c_fd.close()
        else:
            # This is the child process
            child_process(c_fd, c_addr)
            return


try:
    main()
finally:
    s.close()
```

Every new connection is handled by a child process. File descriptors that were open in the parent (such as the client socket returned by the `accept` call) are *already* available in the client. We just need to make sure we close the client socket in the parent, since it's already been inherited by the child.

---

The story is mostly the same if you're spawning subprocesses using the `subprocess` module, because `subprocess` is just calling `fork()` and `exec()` under the hood. This is why I said "subprocess" and "child process" are synonyms.

There's a catch, though. Two of them, in fact:

1. By default, `subprocess` will close all open file descriptors before spawning a child process. Fortunately, there is a `close_fds` keyword argument to disable that behavior.
2. Unfortunately, even if we disable the `close_fds` behavior in `subprocess`, the file descriptors returned by `accept` have the `CLOSE_ON_EXEC` flag set, which means they get closed by the kernel when a process calls `exec`.

But no worries, we can work around this by clearing the `CLOSE_ON_EXEC` flag like this:

```
c_fd, c_addr = s.accept()
flags = fcntl.fcntl(c_fd, fcntl.F_GETFD, 0)
fcntl.fcntl(c_fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, flags & ~fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
```

Afer that, the socket will be inherited by processes spawned using `subprocess.call` and friends. For example, if we rewrite our parent code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fcntl
import socket
import subprocess


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                  socket.SOCK_STREAM|socket.SOCK_CLOEXEC)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('localhost', 2049))
s.listen(5)


def main():
    while True:
        c_fd, c_addr = s.accept()
        flags = fcntl.fcntl(c_fd, fcntl.F_GETFD, 0)
        fcntl.fcntl(c_fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, flags & ~fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
        print('new connection from', c_addr)
        # Here we call the child command, passing the
        # integer file descriptor as the first argument.
        subprocess.check_call(['python', 'socketchild.py',
                         '{}'.format(c_fd.fileno()), c_addr[0]],
                        close_fds=False)
        c_fd.close()


try:
    main()
finally:
    s.close()
```

We can then write child code that uses the `socket.fromfd` method to convert that integer file descriptor back into a socket:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys


def child_process(fd, addr):
    while True:
        data = fd.recv(10)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        print('read:', data)

    print('client {} has disconnected'.format(addr))


def main():
    fdno = int(sys.argv[1])
    print('got fd:', fdno)
    addr = sys.argv[2]
    fd = socket.fromfd(fdno, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    child_process(fd, addr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have to sincerely apologize because it seems that I have misused the terminology "parent process and child process".  Instead of child process I meant subprocess.

My "main" python script is calling another script using the syntax:  subprocess.call(["python3", "second_process.py"])

Many apologies again for the misunderstanding caused by my incorrect terminology.  I will have to fix my question.

Comment: I am not sure how you are differentiate "child process" and "subprocess", which I would argue are just different words for the same thing. Perhaps if you could show your code that difference would be clear.

Comment: I edited my previous comment because I hit <enter> too soon.  I can definitely post some code but it will take me probably a couple hours to get a MWE.  Arguably I should just done this in the first place.

Comment: I've added some information to the answer that might help out.

Comment: Those first 3 lines fixed my issue instantly.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Python code snippet

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

socket reuse address is the key point to note here

You can then use

sock.file_no to pass it on to client.

client can use

```
s_client = socket.socket(<filehandle from parent>, socket.AF_INET,
                  socket.SOCK_STREAM))
```